# Can openVINO model optimiser be used to convert tensorflow ann models?

Tags: tensorflow, openvino, inference-engine

I trained an ANN model as saved it as .h5 file.Then I converted the model into tensorflow model and got `'savedmodel.pb'` and `'variables'` folder.
Then I used model optimiser openvino to generate IR files using:

```
python3 mo_tf.py --input_model saved_model.pb
```

But I get the following error:

```
[ FRAMEWORK ERROR ]  Error parsing message
TensorFlow cannot read the model file: "/home/user/Downloads/OpenVino/dldt-2019/model-optimizer/saved_model.pb" is incorrect TensorFlow model file
```

Can `openVINO` be used to convert `ANN` models in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenVINO does not support Keras model format.

I guess you got an error from model optimizer because your model is not frozen.

There are a lot of scripts which can be used to convert a Keras model to a frozen Tensorflow graph. I can recommend [this one](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow) for example.

Hope it will help.